# Indoor Mapping and Localization for Drones

Tags: ros, drone, 3d-navigation, ardrone-autonomy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am assembling a drone using the *Intel® Aero Compute Board*, *Intel® Aero Vision Accessory Kit (Intel® RealSense™ R200 stereo camera)* and other sensors. I don't know where to start and which packages to use. My goal is to build a map, and let the drone navigate and localize in the environment.  I would like to know the existence of any package for Mapping and Localization. Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277406/indoor-mapping-and-localization-for-drones/) by [Andreluizfc](https://answers.ros.org/users/32882/andreluizfc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2017-12-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

- For SLAM: [rtabmap](http://introlab.github.io/rtabmap/)
- To use your realsense with ros you need the [corresponding node](http://wiki.ros.org/RealSense)

However I highly recommend that you do all the [ros tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials) first.

---

Originally posted by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) with karma: 1504 on 2017-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andreluizfc](https://answers.ros.org/users/32882/andreluizfc/) on 2017-12-06**:
How about an AMCL algorithm? I'll sometimes upload a map and try to perform localization. I'm good with concepts, but not practice. Thanks!

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-12-06**:
You could use[depthimage_to_laserscan](http://wiki.ros.org/depthimage_to_laserscan) to convert your 3d image to 2d lidar data for amcl. But thats not very useful for flying objects where the xy plane changes with the height. Assuming with Drone you refer to an UAV.

**Comment by [Andreluizfc](https://answers.ros.org/users/32882/andreluizfc/) on 2017-12-06**:
It's a quadrotor, yes! My intention is navigation in a fixed Z altitude. I'll model possible obstacles with 3D point cloud and avoid during the navigation.

**Comment by [Andreluizfc](https://answers.ros.org/users/32882/andreluizfc/) on 2017-12-08**:
Besides RTABmap and GMapping, would you recommend other package for building 2D maps? Thanks again, you're being very helpful!

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-12-08**:
[hector_mapping](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_slam) might be more useful for you then gmapping because of missing wheel odometry.